Generic typescript function to handle retry with backoff for google apis
I am trying to create a generic function to handle a retry with backoff to interact with google apis, in case I hit the quotaExceeded error, as I have a lot of requests to process.
I am trying to find ideas to get a nice function, my issue is more about typescript type resolution I guess ?
Idealy I would like a function that accepts three parameters like this
With the second argument properly type by typescript, not any type please !
All is about getting the parameters infered in this function
retryWithBackoff(
google.admin({ version: "directory_v1" }).members.insert,
 {
   auth: token,
   groupKey: group_key,
   requestBody: member,
   alt:"json"
},
[1000,5000,10000]
)

I could wrap the function google.admin({ version: "directory_v1" }).members.insert
into another function and solve my problems easily, submitting a generic function to the retry with backoff, but I wish something less cumbersome, as my taste goes, I would prefer to avoid to create a function like that
const fn =async()=>google.admin({ version: "directory_v1" }).members.insert(
{
   auth: token,
   groupKey: group_key,
   requestBody: member,
   alt:"json"
}
)
retryWithBackoff(fn,[1000,5000,10000])


I could create a bind function too but I wish to preserve the typescript inference.
I tried multiple approach, but I think I am chewing a hard bone because the googleapis package provides multiple signature for each function and I have a hard time to get the typescript signature right
For example the google.admin({ version: "directory_v1" }).members.insert has these functions
 insert(params: Params$Resource$Members$Insert, options: StreamMethodOptions): GaxiosPromise<Readable>;
 insert(params?: Params$Resource$Members$Insert, options?: MethodOptions): GaxiosPromise<Schema$Member>;
 insert(params: Params$Resource$Members$Insert, options: StreamMethodOptions | BodyResponseCallback<Readable>, callback: BodyResponseCallback<Readable>): void;
 insert(params: Params$Resource$Members$Insert, options: MethodOptions | BodyResponseCallback<Schema$Member>, callback: BodyResponseCallback<Schema$Member>): void;
 insert(params: Params$Resource$Members$Insert, callback: BodyResponseCallback<Schema$Member>): void;
 insert(callback: BodyResponseCallback<Schema$Member>): void;

The second signature is the one I want
I saw that GAxios provides a retry, but no backoff with incremental delays and I can't find it in the googleapis package anyway
My question in the end is more about how to deal and infer the proper function and arguments when we have multiple signature of the same function, I guess ?
I tried that approach but could not make it work
Do you know library to deal with this backoff with incremental delays, I am up for it !
Or any direction on how to set up my typescript types right ?
Thank you a lot !
Here a basic function I tried but it doesn't work, I did not keep all my iterations,
But here an example as stack asks
export async function retryWithBackOff<T extends ((...arg0: any[]) => any | Function)>(
    fn: T,
    args: Parameters<T>,
    backOffs: number[]
): Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<T>>> {


    const wait = (delay: number) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, delay))


    for (let i = 0; i < backOffs.length; i++) {
        try {
            const res = await fn(...args)
            return res

        } catch (error: any) {
            const is_error_403 = error.code && error.code === 403
            const is_error_quota = true // I need to solve this more properly I know ^^
            if (is_error_403 && is_error_quota) {
                console.warn(`Quota exeeced. Retrying attempt ${i} in ${backOffs[i]} ms ...`)
                await wait(backOffs[i]);
            }
            else {
                throw error
            }

        }
    }
    throw new Error("Failed after all the retries")
}

